# Relay mutation on plain array is not working

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do mutations on plain array via relay.

I am trying to add a new tag to a post.
It does not get updated on client-side after being successfully added on the server-side.

I have to manually reload to see the new tag.
I have tried both `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` and `this.props.relay.forceFetch()`, but to no avail.

Also, tried `FIELDS_CHANGE` for post.

GraphQL Schema:

```
Post {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  tags: [Tag!]!
}

Tag {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

AddTagToPostMutation:

```
  static fragments = {
    post: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Post {
        id
        tags
      }
    `,
  }

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation { addTagToPost }`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      name: this.props.tag.name,
    };
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on AddTagToPostMutationPayload {
        tag {
          id
          name
        }
        post {
          id
          tags
        }
      }
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'REQUIRED_CHILDREN',
      children: [Relay.QL`
        fragment on AddTagToPostMutationPayload {
          tag {
            id
            name
          }
          post {
            id
            tags
          }
        }
      `],
    }];
  }

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      tag: {
        name: this.props.tag.name,
      },
      post: {
        id: this.props.post.id,
      },
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As freiksenet already pointed out, `FIELDS_CHANGE` should be used in `getConfigs()` function. I took your schema, implemented the GraphQL types, server-side and client-side mutation to add tag to a post. The client-side gets updated successfully. I'm going to just elaborate the solution in my answer.

First, check your server-side mutation. My implementation uses [graphql](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) and [graphql-relay](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) libraries and looks like below. Notice that the output of the server-side mutation is a post to which a tag has been added. This post is the one whose ID was provided as input.

```
const AddTagToPostMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'AddTagToPost',
  inputFields: {
    postId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
  },
  outputFields: {
    post: {
      type: PostType,
      resolve: ({id}) => getPost(id),
    },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({postId, name}) => {
    const id = fromGlobalId(postId).id;
    addTagToPost(id, name);
    return {id};
  },
});
```

Using [graphiql](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql), you can test your mutation:

```
mutation {
  addTagToPost(input:{
      postId: "UG9zdDpwb3N0Mg==" 
      name:"a new tag name" 
      clientMutationId:"123244"}) {
    post {
      id
      text
      tags {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added a field `posts` for all posts to the root query. Using [graphiql](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql), I first checked the post IDs and used one above.

Using [react-relay](https://github.com/facebook/relay), the client-side mutation code looks like below. It is passed a prop `post` whose ID is used as input variable in `getVariables()` function. In the `getConfigs()` function, we specify that `post` field has to be updated. The association between the payload field `post` and the passed prop `post` is established using `FIELDS_CHANGE` mutation type.

```
export default class AddTagToPostMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{addTagToPost}`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      postId: this.props.post.id,
      name: this.props.name,
    };
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on AddTagToPostPayload {
        post {
          id,
          tags {
            id,
            name,
          }
        }
      }
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        post: this.props.post.id,
      },
    }];
  }

  static fragments = {
    post: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Post {
        id,
      }
    `,
  };
}
```

The client-side mutation is invoked like this:

```
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new AddTagToPostMutation({
      post: postToModify,
      name: tagName,
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just use FIELDS_CHANGE in such situations.

```
  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {post: this.props.post.id},
    }];
  }

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      post: {
        id: this.props.post.id,
        tags: [...this.props.post.tags, this.props.tag],
      },
    };
  }
```

Comment: I did try FIELDS_CHANGE too, but didn't work either.

Comment: @Joon Could you check what server actually returns to Relay from mutation request (you can eg use React Dev Tools or just chrome Network tab)? Do you see optimistic response 'blink' at first, as if first adding a tag and then removing?